# MySQL insert doesn't work, no error message

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to insert a row into an InnoDB table that has previously worked fine for years and now I get

> Query OK, 1 row affected

yet nothing shows up in the table. I'm running the query right from the command line interface. There are no such issues with any other tables in the same database.

The tables have just recently been converted to InnoDB from MyISAM.

I have also run "show innodb status" and as far as I can tell there are no problems. Also, everything works fine on a local copy of the database.

How can I find out where it fails and why do I not get an error message?

---

show create table:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tablename | CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `field0` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field1` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `field2` text NOT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field5` varchar(24) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Table structure:

```
mysql> describe tablename;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field0     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field1     | char(2)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field2     | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field3     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field4     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field5     | varchar(24)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Insert statement:

> INSERT INTO `db`.`tablename` (`field0`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`) VALUES ('3', 'en', 'text', '', '', '335783958');

MySQL variables:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment                | 1
| auto_increment_offset                   | 1
| autocommit                              | ON
| automatic_sp_privileges                 | ON
| back_log                                | 50
| basedir                                 | /usr/
| big_tables                              | OFF
| binlog_cache_size                       | 32768
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF
| binlog_format                           | STATEMENT
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                 | 8388608
| character_set_client                    | latin1
| character_set_connection                | latin1
| character_set_database                  | latin1
| character_set_filesystem                | binary
| character_set_results                   | latin1
| character_set_server                    | latin1
| character_set_system                    | utf8
| character_sets_dir                      | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
| collation_connection                    | latin1_swedish_ci
| collation_database                      | latin1_swedish_ci
| collation_server                        | latin1_swedish_ci
| completion_type                         | 0
| concurrent_insert                       | 1
| connect_timeout                         | 10
| datadir                                 | /media/...
| date_format                             | %Y-%m-%d
| datetime_format                         | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
| default_week_format                     | 0
| delay_key_write                         | ON
| delayed_insert_limit                    | 100
| delayed_insert_timeout                  | 300
| delayed_queue_size                      | 1000
| div_precision_increment                 | 4
| engine_condition_pushdown               | ON
| error_count                             | 0
| event_scheduler                         | OFF
| expire_logs_days                        | 10
| flush                                   | OFF
| flush_time                              | 0
| foreign_key_checks                      | ON
| ft_boolean_syntax                       | + -><()~*:""&|
| ft_max_word_len                         | 84
| ft_min_word_len                         | 4
| ft_query_expansion_limit                | 20
| ft_stopword_file                        | (built-in)
| general_log                             | OFF
| general_log_file                        | /media/...
| group_concat_max_len                    | 1024
| have_community_features                 | YES
| have_compress                           | YES
| have_crypt                              | YES
| have_csv                                | YES
| have_dynamic_loading                    | YES
| have_geometry                           | YES
| have_innodb                             | YES
| have_ndbcluster                         | NO
| have_openssl                            | DISABLED
| have_partitioning                       | YES
| have_query_cache                        | YES
| have_rtree_keys                         | YES
| have_ssl                                | DISABLED
| have_symlink                            | YES
| hostname                                | server
| identity                                | 0
| ignore_builtin_innodb                   | OFF
| init_connect                            |
| init_file                               |
| init_slave                              |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index              | ON
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size         | 1048576
| innodb_autoextend_increment             | 8
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                | 1
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608
| innodb_checksums                        | ON
| innodb_commit_concurrency               | 0
| innodb_concurrency_tickets              | 500
| innodb_data_file_path                   | ibdata1:10M:autoextend
| innodb_data_home_dir                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                      | ON
| innodb_fast_shutdown                    | 1
| innodb_file_io_threads                  | 4
| innodb_file_per_table                   | OFF
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          | 1
| innodb_flush_method                     |
| innodb_force_recovery                   | 0
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                | 50
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF
| innodb_log_buffer_size                  | 1048576
| innodb_log_file_size                    | 5242880
| innodb_log_files_in_group               | 2
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90
| innodb_max_purge_lag                    | 0
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups              | 1
| innodb_open_files                       | 300
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout              | OFF
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                | ON
| innodb_support_xa                       | ON
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                  | 20
| innodb_table_locks                      | ON
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 8
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000
| innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm | ON
| insert_id                               | 0
| interactive_timeout                     | 28800
| join_buffer_size                        | 131072
| keep_files_on_create                    | OFF
| key_buffer_size                         | 16777216
| key_cache_age_threshold                 | 300
| key_cache_block_size                    | 1024
| key_cache_division_limit                | 100
| language                                | /usr/share/mysql/english/
| large_files_support                     | ON
| large_page_size                         | 0
| large_pages                             | OFF
| last_insert_id                          | 0
| lc_time_names                           | en_US
| license                                 | GPL
| local_infile                            | ON
| locked_in_memory                        | OFF
| log                                     | OFF
| log_bin                                 | OFF
| log_bin_trust_function_creators         | OFF
| log_bin_trust_routine_creators          | OFF
| log_error                               | /var/log/mysql/error.log
| log_output                              | FILE
| log_queries_not_using_indexes           | OFF
| log_slave_updates                       | OFF
| log_slow_queries                        | OFF
| log_warnings                            | 1
| long_query_time                         | 10.000000
| low_priority_updates                    | OFF
| lower_case_file_system                  | OFF
| lower_case_table_names                  | 0
| max_allowed_packet                      | 16777216
| max_binlog_cache_size                   | 18446744073709547520
| max_binlog_size                         | 104857600
| max_connect_errors                      | 10
| max_connections                         | 151
| max_delayed_threads                     | 20
| max_error_count                         | 64
| max_heap_table_size                     | 16777216
| max_insert_delayed_threads              | 20
| max_join_size                           | 18446744073709551615
| max_length_for_sort_data                | 1024
| max_prepared_stmt_count                 | 16382
| max_relay_log_size                      | 0
| max_seeks_for_key                       | 18446744073709551615
| max_sort_length                         | 1024
| max_sp_recursion_depth                  | 0
| max_tmp_tables                          | 32
| max_user_connections                    | 0
| max_write_lock_count                    | 18446744073709551615
| min_examined_row_limit                  | 0
| multi_range_count                       | 256
| myisam_data_pointer_size                | 6
| myisam_max_sort_file_size               | 9223372036853727232
| myisam_mmap_size                        | 18446744073709551615
| myisam_recover_options                  | BACKUP
| myisam_repair_threads                   | 1
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                 | 8388608                                                                                   |
| myisam_stats_method                     | nulls_unequal                                                                             |
| myisam_use_mmap                         | OFF                                                                                       |
| net_buffer_length                       | 16384                                                                                     |
| net_read_timeout                        | 30                                                                                        |
| net_retry_count                         | 10                                                                                        |
| net_write_timeout                       | 60                                                                                        |
| new                                     | OFF                                                                                       |
| old                                     | OFF                                                                                       |
| old_alter_table                         | OFF                                                                                       |
| old_passwords                           | OFF                                                                                       |
| open_files_limit                        | 1024                                                                                      |
| optimizer_prune_level                   | 1                                                                                         |
| optimizer_search_depth                  | 62                                                                                        |
| optimizer_switch                        | index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on |
| pid_file                                | /media/...                                                                                |
| plugin_dir                              | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin                                                                     |
| port                                    | 3306                                                                                      |
| preload_buffer_size                     | 32768                                                                                     |
| profiling                               | OFF                                                                                       |
| profiling_history_size                  | 15                                                                                        |
| protocol_version                        | 10                                                                                        |
| pseudo_thread_id                        | 1052520                                                                                   |
| query_alloc_block_size                  | 8192                                                                                      |
| query_cache_limit                       | 1048576                                                                                   |
| query_cache_min_res_unit                | 4096                                                                                      |
| query_cache_size                        | 16777216                                                                                  |
| query_cache_type                        | ON                                                                                        |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate            | OFF                                                                                       |
| query_prealloc_size                     | 8192                                                                                      |
| rand_seed1                              |                                                                                           |
| rand_seed2                              |                                                                                           |
| range_alloc_block_size                  | 4096                                                                                      |
| read_buffer_size                        | 131072                                                                                    |
| read_only                               | OFF                                                                                       |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                    | 262144                                                                                    |
| relay_log                               |                                                                                           |
| relay_log_index                         |                                                                                           |
| relay_log_info_file                     | relay-log.info                                                                            |
| relay_log_purge                         | ON                                                                                        |
| relay_log_space_limit                   | 0                                                                                         |
| report_host                             |                                                                                           |
| report_password                         |                                                                                           |
| report_port                             | 3306                                                                                      |
| report_user                             |                                                                                           |
| rpl_recovery_rank                       | 0                                                                                         |
| secure_auth                             | OFF                                                                                       |
| secure_file_priv                        |                                                                                           |
| server_id                               | 0                                                                                         |
| skip_external_locking                   | ON                                                                                        |
| skip_name_resolve                       | OFF                                                                                       |
| skip_networking                         | OFF                                                                                       |
| skip_show_database                      | OFF                                                                                       |
| slave_compressed_protocol               | OFF                                                                                       |
| slave_exec_mode                         | STRICT                                                                                    |
| slave_load_tmpdir                       | /tmp                                                                                      |
| slave_net_timeout                       | 3600                                                                                      |
| slave_skip_errors                       | OFF                                                                                       |
| slave_transaction_retries               | 10                                                                                        |
| slow_launch_time                        | 2                                                                                         |
| slow_query_log                          | OFF                                                                                       |
| slow_query_log_file                     | /media/...                                                                                |
| socket                                  | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock                                                               |
| sort_buffer_size                        | 2097144                                                                                   |
| sql_auto_is_null                        | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_big_selects                         | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_big_tables                          | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_buffer_result                       | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_log_bin                             | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_log_off                             | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_log_update                          | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_low_priority_updates                | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_max_join_size                       | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| sql_mode                                |                                                                                           |
| sql_notes                               | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_quote_show_create                   | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_safe_updates                        | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_select_limit                        | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| sql_slave_skip_counter                  |                                                                                           |
| sql_warnings                            | OFF                                                                                       |
| ssl_ca                                  |                                                                                           |
| ssl_capath                              |                                                                                           |
| ssl_cert                                |                                                                                           |
| ssl_cipher                              |                                                                                           |
| ssl_key                                 |                                                                                           |
| storage_engine                          | InnoDB                                                                                    |
| sync_binlog                             | 0                                                                                         |
| sync_frm                                | ON                                                                                        |
| system_time_zone                        | CEST                                                                                      |
| table_definition_cache                  | 256                                                                                       |
| table_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                                                                                        |
| table_open_cache                        | 64                                                                                        |
| table_type                              | InnoDB                                                                                    |
| thread_cache_size                       | 8                                                                                         |
| thread_handling                         | one-thread-per-connection                                                                 |
| thread_stack                            | 196608                                                                                    |
| time_format                             | %H:%i:%s                                                                                  |
| time_zone                               | SYSTEM                                                                                    |
| timed_mutexes                           | OFF                                                                                       |
| timestamp                               | 1375179731                                                                                |
| tmp_table_size                          | 16777216                                                                                  |
| tmpdir                                  | /tmp                                                                                      |
| transaction_alloc_block_size            | 8192                                                                                      |
| transaction_prealloc_size               | 4096                                                                                      |
| tx_isolation                            | REPEATABLE-READ                                                                           |
| unique_checks                           | ON                                                                                        |
| updatable_views_with_limit              | YES                                                                                       |
| version                                 | 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1                                                                         |
| version_comment                         | (Ubuntu)                                                                                  |
| version_compile_machine                 | x86_64                                                                                    |
| version_compile_os                      | debian-linux-gnu                                                                          |
| wait_timeout                            | 28800                                                                                     |
| warning_count                           | 0                                                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
274 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Are you commiting your insert? it may be rolling back after the insert if you do not

Comment: After your insert query, try running another query that is just `commit;`

Comment: "Query OK, 0 rows affected" and the entry isn't in the table after the commit.

Comment: Autocommit is also enabled, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert 'text' into a char(2) field this will generate a warning of truncated data, If you are not seeing that warning then there is something very strange going on with your configuration, or the schema and query shown is not the same as the one you are running

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

That said, there is nothing wrong with the query or with the schema that you have posted, I can only assume that the problem is due to something you have left out of your question whilst simplifying your issue.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO tablename (field0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) VALUES ('3', 'text', 'text', '', '', '335783958');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'field1' at row 1 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from tablename;
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| field0 | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|      3 | te     | text   |        |        | 335783958 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Please post the real `CREATE TABLE` syntax and your actual query for us to be able to help any further

I appreciate this may not give a full answer but it ios too long for a comment

Comment: "You are trying to insert 'text' into a char(2) field"  
That happened while redacting the data, sorry. The real query I tried had two characters.  
I added the create table output and the mysql configuration to the original post.  
I should also add that the tables in the database have just recently been converted to InnoDB (ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE = InnoDB;), but I can't say if the problem started at the same time.

Comment: Sorry there is nothing at all wrong with the stuff you have posted. Anything else is just guess work. Have you tried checking your table mysql> check table tablename; or dumping / restoring your db in case something has gone very screwy

Comment: I tried to avoid deleting and restoring tables, but in the end it fixed the problem. Dropped the table, restored it and no more problems. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

your insert is worked and inserted one row , if you see last inserted row you will find it.

**BUT**  i think you want update some empty columns only and you should do `UPDATE` not `insert`.

Comment: Wow you must be psychic to know that the user wants to update blank columns as they never say anything about that.

Comment: because maybe he think that he will insert to that empty column but in fact its update

Comment: and im psychic in mysql yes :)

Comment: I searched for field5 = "335783958" and it turned out empty, so I don't think the insert worked. Also, when I order the table by the numbers in field5, the row doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ended up here having the same problem.

Deleted and created the table, no success.

in the end, it turned out I was in the middle of an transaction. A commit solved all my problems.

Answer (score -1):

Writing this as I ended up here after having the same problem while using python.

**Be sure to commit** your changes before you close your cursor or nothing will appear on your db (and, to **rollback** if something doesn't work, of course :). I forgot to do that and that's why the query executed properly but my db table didn't update. Also, I had no kind of error showing since there was no mistake.

Python example:

```py
try:
    stmt = "INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    params = (value1, value2)
    cur.execute(stmt, params)
    connection.commit()  # <-- THIS
    cur.close()
    connection.close()
except Exception as err:
    connection.rollback()
    cur.close()
    connection.close()
    print(f"Error: {err}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know what answer you're talking about. Mine is the only one with a python example too

Comment: "Be sure to commit your changes" is the relevant part. Whether you have this problem in a Python application or not does not make any difference

Comment: Lots of answers in different questions answer in such a way and it's normal because they're answering the same question. Problem is, "what is the best"? Do you stop answering in a post just because someone else did it even though the answer is low-effort or not good?